# MariaDB: Could not connect: unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, mysql, raspberry-pi, apache2, mariadb

I have recently turned my Raspberry to a web server, which could be connected via SSH from either outside or inside the network.

However, when I tried to connect to the database (MariaDB 10 + Apache2) by using DBCP (a MySQL connector):

- I can connect to the database if I'm inside the network
- I used to successfully connect to my server from outside network, but not
  anymore.

Instead, I got an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to blabla.com:8080 : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:175)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1107)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:502)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:279)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2343)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2329)
            ... 14 more
```

**What I tried:**

1. Set validation query to `SELECT 1`
2. Increase time out
3. Completely remove Apche2+MariaDB and set them up again

And finally, none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just do a telnet and check ping to port is happening properly or not ? and try to access MariaDB only (not via Raspberry pi) and post the outcome ...